# Authlogic Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I am having a weird issue with Authlogic in Rails 3. I followed this how-to [here](http://www.dixis.com/?p=352) but I get:

```
NoMethodError in PeopleController#my

undefined method `login_field' for Object:Class

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:33:in `current_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:39:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:44:in `require_user'
```

Any ideas how to get this fixed?

Comment: you'll need to actually post what code is in those relevant lines in your application_controller in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: FYI I looked at that tutorial and a bunch of others.  In my opinion, they let you make way too many changes before actually running the app and verifying what you have so far is working.  I did a more code/verify, code/verify baby step approach and was able to eventually get it working.  I have some notes and may publish them up to this site and/or my blog once I work out the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relevant source?  I think you made 2 mistakes

1. You tried to configure acts_as_authentic options in people_controller.rb instead of in the model (presumably called app/models/people.rb in your code)
2. You didn't wrap this code in the "acts_as_authentic" method block

Try this in app/models/people.rb

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.login_field = :email
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the login field to the migration? You can remove it.