# Authlogic undefined method `login_field' for Object:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authlogic

I'm trying to set up Authlogic as my default authentication system.  I want the user to be able to log in using either their username or email.  To accomplish this, I did the following:

app/model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #add authlogic authentications
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.find_by_login_method :find_by_username_or_email
  end 

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :username, :presence => true, 
                       :length => { :within => 3..20 }, 
                       :uniqueness => true, 
                       :format => { :with => /\A[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9]\z/ }

  validates :email, :presence => true, 
                    :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i }, 
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensative => false },
                    :length => { :maximum => 255 }

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 }

  def self.find_by_username_or_email(username_or_email)
    find_by_username(username_or_email) || find_by_email(username_or_email)
  end

end
```

app/model/session.rb:

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

app/controller/sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @session = Session.new
  end

  def create
    username = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:username_or_email]).username
    username ||= params[:session][:username_or_email]
    @session = Session.new(params[:session])

    if @session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default :users
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_session.destroy
    redirect_back_or_default new_session_url
  end

end
```

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Sign In</h1>

<%= render 'login_form' %>
```

app/views/sessions/_login_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @session do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Username or Email' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :login %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", :class => "button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => :create

  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :signout
end
```

When I run the rails server and try to connect to `http://localhost:3000/signin`, it gives the following error:

```
undefined method `login_field' for Object:Class
```

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:90:in `login_field'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:213:in `login_field'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:118:in `initialize'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/activation.rb:48:in `initialize'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/klass.rb:64:in `initialize'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:79:in `initialize'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:37:in `new'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:37:in `find'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `current_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:33:in `require_no_user'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__2106190539632311804__process_action__1284228636937718599__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
sass (3.1.1) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

I don't really understand why this is happening.  If I'm using `find_by_login_method`, then why does Authlogic even need `login_field`?

**Update**

I updated my code to match Olivier L's answer.  The controller isn't working, but I think it's a lot closer.

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #add authlogic authentications
  acts_as_authentic do |c| 
    c.session_class = Session
    c.find_by_login_method :find_by_username_or_email
  end

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :username, :presence => true, 
                       :length => { :within => 3..20 }, 
                       :uniqueness => true, 
                       :format => { :with => /\A[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9]\z/ }

  validates :email, :presence => true, 
                    :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i }, 
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensative => false },
                    :length => { :maximum => 255 }

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 }

  def self.find_by_username_or_email(username_or_email)
    find_by_username(username_or_email) || find_by_email(username_or_email)
  end

end
```

app/models/session.rb:

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base
  authenticate_with User
end
```

I'm now getting the error:

```
undefined method `find_by_login_method' for #<Class:0x00000101a77ba8>
```

Here's the application trace:

```
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:984:in `method_missing'
app/models/user.rb:30:in `block in <class:User>'
authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/base.rb:36:in `acts_as_authentic'
app/models/user.rb:28:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
app/models/session.rb:2:in `<class:Session>'
app/models/session.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `current_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:33:in `require_no_user'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__1226739957950205446__process_action__742106135127651722__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
sass (3.1.1) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Just noticed this is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948682/authlogic-rails-3), although the latter looks orphaned and unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** ok, I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122262/using-different-session-model-name-in-authlogic) which is basically the same as yours.  His accepted answer would indicate you need to do this:

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base
  authenticate_with User
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c| 
    c.session_class = Session
    c.find_by_login_method :find_by_username_or_email
  end
end
```

---

Look [here](http://www.sentia.com.au/2009/06/adding-your-own-login-method-to-authlogic/) for a good way to implement multi-login-field authentication.

---

Just in case the link ever becomes broken, here's what Michael Cindric suggests in his blog (edited to use your classes' and fields' names):

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base
  find_by_login_method :find_by_username_or_email
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_username_or_email(login)
    find_by_username(login) || find_by_email(login)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, I changed it to match what you put but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then I guess the `login_field` still needs to be set in order to pick up the user's input.  Add `c.login_field = :login` to your `acts_as_authentic` call.  Might have to create a virtual field in the User class for it, not sure.

Comment: Well I tried adding `c.login_field = :username` and that didn't do the trick.  Then I put `c.login_field = :login`, and I wrote a quick getter and setter for `login`.  Still no luck.

Comment: Okay, I think your update got me a lot closer to the correct answer.  I updated my answer to match what you wrote and I added the new error and stack trace.

Comment: I also tried adding find_by_login_method to the session class how you had it before, and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @helixed: when you added the `find_by_login_method` call to the `Session` class, did you remove the same call from the `acts_as_authentic` block?

Comment: Well, I never did get it to work.  I wiped the 'Session' model and 'SessionsController', and instead made a 'UserSession' model and 'UserSessionsController'.  It worked, but it seems like a cheap fix.  Still, you're post and comments were instrumental in getting it to work.  Thanks for all the help.